# How to use different versions of node/npm on a single system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

My questions says it all.

Is it possible to install and use a different version of npm per project on a single system?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, unless a project like the RVM for Node exists... I'm more curious as to why... Edit: [something like this](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup it is possible to use different version of **npm** per project in a single system.

> If you are using *Mac* or *Linux* based systems then you can user [Node
>   Version Manager (nvm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm).
>
> For better idea about installation and usages of nvm you can take a
>   look at their [github ripo](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).
>
> But if you are using windows then you have two alternative to nvm. [NVM
>   for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) and
>   [nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist). You will find
>   installation and usages instruction on the likes.

Hope it helps you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [n](https://github.com/tj/n) created my [TJ Holowaychuk](https://github.com/tj). Which is simple flavour of node/iojs binary management, no subshells, no profile setup, no convoluted api, just simple.